# How should I filter by category without scanning full database?

Tags: mongodb, database

I need to build a database that allows me to query over all the entries in a category. There is only one category property I will be filtering over, so it seems like it should be possible to do these queries without searching over the full database. Also, I want to use mongodb if possible.

The approach I'm considering is to create a collection for each category, but I'm new to this, so I'm not sure what the implications of that might be. I expect to have a large number of categories that will be frequently added to the database. Also, I expect most of the categories to have only 1-10 entries in them with a few exceptionally large categories (i.e. Poisson distributed).

Comment: One collection for all items, with index on `category` field should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please the documenation on namespace limitations:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/
- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections

Why would you create one collection per category? You would not even do that with
a RDBMS. Inside a RDBMS you would use one table with one 'category' column indexed.
The same approach is doable with MongoDB and basically works exactly the same way.
In addition you should be able to shard such a collection if necessary for scalability reasons.